# How to avoid PHP Notice "Undefined offset: 0" without checking each field of array

Tags: php, arrays

i have the following array:

```
    $keyvisual_data = array(
        'video_file'            => $row->field_field_video[0]['rendered']['#item']['uri'],
        'bild_file'             => $row->field_field_bild[0]['rendered']['#item']['uri'],
        'subline_src'           => $row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_key_titel['und'][0]['safe_value'],
        'screenreader_src'      => $row->field_field_alt_screenreader[0]['rendered']['#markup'],
        'alt_src'               => $row->field_field_bild[0]['rendered']['#item']['alt']
    );
```

it might happen that some of the fields are not set, this is okay. in fact i am getting this PHP notice:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in bafa_insert_keyvisual() ...........

is it somehow possible to assign a default value to each key in case it is undefined WITHOUT checking each field of the array manually?

thanks for help

Comment: Isn't the problem really with the $row->field_field_video source array that you're assigning from, rather than the $keyvisual_data array? Have you verified that $row->field_field_video[0] is defined?

Comment: those are optional fields. sometimes they hold a value, sometimes not. i am checking this later in my function and then act depending on whether they have a value or not.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, add `@` before the field like:

```
$keyvisual_data = array(
    'video_file'            => @$row->field_field_video[0]['rendered']['#item']['uri'],
    'bild_file'             => @$row->field_field_bild[0]['rendered']['#item']['uri'],
    'subline_src'           => @$row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_key_titel['und'][0]['safe_value'],
    'screenreader_src'      => @$row->field_field_alt_screenreader[0]['rendered']['#markup'],
    'alt_src'               => @$row->field_field_bild[0]['rendered']['#item']['alt']
);
```

and then initialize the nulls:

```
if($keyvisual_data['video_file'] === null)
    $keyvisual_data['video_file'] = $default_video_file;
```

etc...

Comment: why has this answer been voted down? it actually does what i want with the least effort. or is there anything problematic with this method of doing it?

Comment: @maze the problem with doing it like that is that it suppresses error for no reason...

Comment: so prefixing something with an @ does nothing but prevent error messages? ... i guess in this case it's okay. because later in my function i check whether a value is present and then act accordingly. but good to know.

Comment: i think isset is the way you should go

Comment: "Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no indication as to why." http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Using the "@" prefix is like hide your dirt below a carpet.

Comment: I agree that `@` should be used as little as absolutely possible. However, I have a valid example of why I'd want exactly that: I have a TypeValidation class with a function that checks a variable's type and content, combining several of the `isset()`, `empty()`, `is_int()`, etc. standard functions. Haviing this wrapped in my own reusable function instead of typing it out every time is immensely time-saving. But each call with an undefined value (which my function will handle just fine) returns a notice error *which is completely useless in my situation*. Now do that 100x in a loop....

Comment: Also, an important point: there is, *as far as I'm aware*, no possible value that can be passed to my function to cause any error of any kind. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Wow! worked like magic... nice go on the `@` attribute, I have totally different situation but surely removed the `Undefined offset 0:`error. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 46):

No there is not

You can do an `isset()`:

```
if(isset($array[0])){
    echo $array[0];
}
else {
  //some error?
}
```

Or if you know that you are only going to be checking index 0:

```
$array = $array + array(null);
```

So if the original `$array[0]` was unset, now it is `null`

Comment: This also seems to work for multi-dimensional arrays. Nice! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could add a shorthand check if each value is null

```
$default_value = "Default value";

$keyvisual_data = array(
        'video_file' => ($row->field_field_video[0]['rendered']['#item']['uri'] == null) ? $default_value : $row->field_field_video[0]['rendered']['#item']['uri']

// etc.. etc...
);
```

A less messy version of this, to explain the code more clearly:

```
<?php

$default_value = "I am a Default value";

$video_file = null;

$new_array = array(
        'video_file' => ($video_file == null) ? $default_value : $video_file
);

// Will output "I am a Default value"
echo $new_array['video_file'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "isset" function to check the existence of the field, and infact its a good coding practice..

```
$keyvisual_data = array(
      'video_file' => isset($rowWrapper->getVideoFile()) ? $rowWrapper->getVideoFile() : "any default value",
       ...
 );
```

or you can use it in this way :

```
if(isset($rowWrapper->getVideoFile()))
{  
     $row['video_file'] = $rowWrapper->getVideoFile();
}
else {
   $row['video_file'] = "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, the structure of the row data object doesnt seem very convinient and error prone. Especially if you are using $row in some other context, too, I would suggest you wrap it in an object:

```
class RowWrapper
{
    private $_row;

    public function __construct($row)
    {
        $this->_row = $row;
    }

    public function getVideoFile()
    {
        if (!isset($row->field_field_video[0])) {
            return null;
        }

        return $row->field_field_video[0]['rendered']['#item']['uri'];
    }

    ...
}

$rowWrapper = new RowWrapper($row);

$keyvisual_data = array(
    'video_file'            => $rowWrapper->getVideoFile(),
    ...
);
```

If you there is only one value e. g. inside of `$row->field_field_video` then it shouldnt be an array. I would use a wrapper class as a kind of anti corruption layer if that strange datastructure comes from a remote source or the like. Otherwise it will creep through your while application with `$row->field_field_video[0]...` stuff all over the place.

I know this is not the fast and easy solution you want, but swallowing errors is never a good idea.