# Weird Undefined offset: 0 error

Tags: php

I've the following PHP code that receives a file from an iOS app.

The information is received and for my debuggin `$file` is setted and has content in all its forms. The original value passed is `btn-7.png` and `$file[0] = btn-7`.

The function is processed and all images are copied to the system as I see them in the folder.... thus I dont know why i am getting this error.

The error appear in the first line available to the function that shows `$_FILES[$file]`

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

EDIT: As I said. No need to do var_dump because I can echo $file. Also I am debbugin from iOS console can't see non-JSON results, I only rely on PHP logs to know the actual error message.

EDIT2: as requested `var_dump(); (I am working from XCode, iOS dev console, not web browser)

```
ob_start();

            var_dump($file);
            $e = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            error_log($e, 0);
```

the result

```
[06-Jun-2013 17:58:26 UTC] string(9) "btn-7.png"`
```

the error

```
[06-Jun-2013 17:24:45 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\igym\classes\shareexercise.php on line 146
```

PHP

```
private function storeFile( $file )
        {
            $file = explode('.',$file);
            $file = $file[0];
            $msg['asd'] = $file;
            echo json_encode($msg);

            if( $_FILES[$file]["type"] !== "image/png" && $_FILES[$file]["size"] < 2048600 )
            {
                $error['error'] = 'There was a problem uploading your picture';
                echo json_encode($error);
                return 0;
            }

            if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'], IMGUPLOADDIR . '/' . $this->userID . '/' . $_FILES[$file]['name'] ) ) {
                return true;
            } else{
                //$error['error'] = 'There was a problem uploading your picture';
                //echo json_encode($error);
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: I would try to `var_dump` $file before line 146.

Comment: that is weird even if you explode(".", null) you get an array with a 0 element.

Comment: @SSHThis As mentioned $file has everything as I can echo it.

Comment: But `var_dump` would show the numeric indices or lack thereof.

Comment: Yes, but if you can `echo $file[0] . $file;` its pretty irelevant

Comment: The error indicates that `$file[0]` is undefined. So I think that perhaps you echo in the wrong place

Comment: Here's an idea, you could try `if(isset($file[0]))` right before `$file = $file[0];` and then `return false` if it isn't.

Comment: @jeroen is not a form. I am receiving this from iOS `AFNetworking` using `AFMultipartFormData`

Comment: You can also manually log something by using `error_log` http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: @SSHThis is it `ISSET()` return true always

Comment: isset should return false if array offset is undefined: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688814/how-to-avoid-php-notice-undefined-offset-0-without-checking-each-field-of-arr 2nd answer by Neal

Comment: I know! thats why is so weird.....

Comment: Please provide a var_dump of both $file and $_FILES.

Comment: Let me clarify - a `var_dump` of `$file` **after** the explode, as well as a dump of `$_FILES`

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES` is an **associative** array, not a numerical array:

From: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

```
$_FILES
An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method.
```

You should `var_dump($_FILES)` and see what the structure looks like. 0 doesn't exist because the index is the field name or some other string.

Aso: [A tutorial on $_FILES](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)

Comment: I think the array in which he is talking about is actually `$file` not `$_FILES`. Although, I did not vote you down.

Comment: Are you sure? 'The error appear in the first line available to the function that shows $_FILES[$file]'

Comment: $_FILES[$file] == $_FILES['btn-7']

Comment: @JonathanThurft please var_dump both `$file` and `$_FILES`

Comment: Please provide the output - and, if you could, point out exactly which line the error is coming from in your code block

Comment: I just provided the var_dump output as per error log and the reason why is displayed like that and not in any other form. also the error always reflect the first line where $_FILE[$file] appears no matter of its location. and as also mentioned, the files copies to the server. It is not a typical error, nor is an issue that is not set

Comment: What about var_dump of $file after the explode?